# Spring 4 REST returning JavaScript call back and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, spring, spring-rest, getorgchart

I am using GetOrgChart, and I really like it.  They have a load from JSON example and their javascript code from their demos looks like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("http://www.getorgchart.com/JsonInitialization/Read?callback=?", function (source) {
        var peopleElement = document.getElementById("people");
        var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
            theme: "helen",
            primaryFields: ["Name", "Title"],
            photoFields: ["Image"],
            linkType: "M",
            enableEdit: false,
            enableDetailsView: false,
            dataSource: source
        });
    });
</script>
```

The URL to get the JSON looks like:

```
http://www.getorgchart.com/JsonInitialization/Read?callback=?
```

but really, you just need:

```
http://www.getorgchart.com/JsonInitialization/Read
```

and this gets back this code:

```
callback( ...JSON here ... );
```

so, not just JSON, but a callback function.

Now, I have a Spring 4 MVC RESTful function that returns the correct JSON.
But, If I just use the URL to get the JSON, such as:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp-be/api/orgCharts/contactId/7
```

I get two nodes that I am expecting, but no lines to connect them.  In this case I think I need to change the URL to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp-be/api/orgCharts/contactId/7?callback=?
```

and I think instead of returning just JSON data, I need to return:

```
callback( ...JSON here ... );
```

My RESTful web-service I have defined in Spring is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/opportunityId/{opportunityId}", 
    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
    headers = "Accept=application/json", 
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<ChartNodeDTO> getOrgChartData(@PathVariable long contactId)
{
    List<ChartNodeDTO> orgChartList = orgChartService.getOrgChartByContactId(contactId);
    return orgChartList;
}
```

The question is ... do I change this to return a String?  On the back-end, I can create a String such as:   String data = "callback(" + json + ");";
But this doesn't seem like the correct way.

I want to return the Javascript code, but I am just tweaking the Spring REST parameters, and doing trial and error before finding the correct solution.
I figured if someone can save me some time, that would be great ... and in the meantime, I will keep trying different things.

Thanks!

Comment: The ?callback= part of the remote URL is if you're dealing with cross-origin data and are thus using JSONP which is not needed for straight-up JSON calls from the same server (assuming you haven't added a JSONP wrapper in your back-end service, which from your code snippet doesn't appear to the be case). Can you include the JSON response from your REST API here? If there are no lines connecting the nodes, it's probably because the originating JSON is incomplete

Comment: I can tell you that the JSON is valid.  From my Spring REST, we have an object that is mapped to JSON from the fasterJacksonMapper, so the JSON itslef is spot on.    My backend is a different server than the HTML page I am using.   I already have a simpleCorsFilter in place that allows me to have the front-end make calls to the back-end without any domain issues.